# background div'a и body - в чем разница?

Tags: html, css

Хочу чтобы картинка на фоне у `body` была ограничена визуально размерами `body`. Но как-то оно себя подругому ведет, нежели я о нем думаю.

Даже  `overflow: hidden;` не помогает.. А div'у он даже не требуется.

Пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/tm8yhoz7/11/

Comment: 1) чтобы исправить - задайте фон для тега html (например, белый) 2) чтобы понять - прочитайте [ответы здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17806691/4041128) (и ответ дубликата)

Comment: @BOPOH спасибо! буду разбираться!

Comment: `body {backgraund-image: url();
backgraund-position: center center;
backgraund-size: cover};`
картинка будет вписываться и подгоняться всегда по размерам блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев ваш пример решил оформить в виде ответа.
Диву в вашем коде не нужно дисплей блок задавать он и так по умолчанию блок.
бэкграунд позишион сделайте центер центер, тогда будет центрироваться по х и у:
Примерно должно быть так как я понимаю:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://kievpravda.com/media/images/10927/main/400.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url('http://kievpravda.com/media/images/10927/main/400.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Также можно задать свойство background-attachment:

Значения:
fixed
Делает фоновое изображение элемента неподвижным.
scroll
Позволяет перемещаться фону вместе с содержимым.
inherit
Наследует значение родителя.
local
Фон фиксируется с учётом поведения элемента. Если элемент имеет прокрутку, то фон будет прокручиваться вместе с содержимым, но фон выходящий за рамки элемента остаётся на месте.

*Я так понимаю вопрос стоял за body на всю ширину и высоту и отступами по умолчанию?

Ну а если нужно обрезать по границе контента в body, то вот:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
html {
    background: #fff;
}
body {
   
    background-image: url('http://kievpravda.com/media/images/10927/main/400.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url('http://kievpravda.com/media/images/10927/main/400.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: добавьте к body стиль `border: 1px solid red`. Все, что находится за красной линией - лишнее. В этом и вопрос автора. Добавьте к тегу html стиль `background-color: white` и вы увидите что действительно хотел получить автор

Comment: @BOPOH, внес необходимые  изменения.