# Css-градиент для body работает некорректно в зависимости от контента

Tags: html, css, css3, градиент

Снова вынужден обратиться за советом. Создал в генераторе градиента такой код:

```
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(212,228,239,1)), color-stop(37%, rgba(212,228,239,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(170,194,209,1)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d4e4ef', endColorstr='#aac2d1', GradientType=1 );
```

(да, возможно это плохо и неэффективно пользоваться такими генераторами, но там быстро работаешь с ползунками цвета и красивый результат на выходе)

Создал пустую страницу со всей минимальной bootstrap-разметкой, в css файле определил этот градиент для тега body - все работает.

```
body {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(212,228,239,1)), color-stop(37%, rgba(212,228,239,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(170,194,209,1)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d4e4ef', endColorstr='#aac2d1', GradientType=1 );
}
```

Но стоит написать любое слово на странице или вставить любой элемент, то градиент перестает быть фоном всей страницы, а становится фоном ровно на высоту блока и повторяется до заполнения всей страницы. То есть добавляю контент и вместо фона градиентом получаю горизонтальные полоски.

Буду рад любым советам или наводкам, почему это происходит. Пробовал определять градиент к тегу html, к контейнеру, но все равно не заработало у меня, как надо. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит [посмотреть здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497871/background-diva-%D0%B8-body-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0/497898#497898)

Answer (score 3):

Лучше прописать

```
html, body{
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Если вы оставите `height: 100%`, то, даже если высота контента превысит эти самые 100%, высота блока `body` останется равной высоте экрана, что может вызвать ряд проблем в дальнейшей вёрстке.

Можете сравнить получаемый градиент в обоих случаях и посмотреть в инспекторе высоту `body` в каждом случае:

- min-height: https://jsfiddle.net/8wzn5hmz/
- height: https://jsfiddle.net/oza10b1s/

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен! Не стоило торопиться с постом вопроса.

Необходимо добавить фиксированную высоту блока. В данном случае меня вполне устраивала высота во весь экран, поэтому мое решение имеет вид:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(212,228,239,1)), color-stop(37%, rgba(212,228,239,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(170,194,209,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(212,228,239,1) 37%, rgba(170,194,209,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d4e4ef', endColorstr='#aac2d1', GradientType=1 );
}
```

Comment: 100% - это относительная высота, а не фиксированная.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Я имел в виду конкретную высоту, а не фиксированную. Так как высота экрана всегда известна, то 100% от экрана - это вполне конкретно и градиент нормально заполняет фон. Если указывать фиксированную высоту, то все тоже будет работать как надо. А вот вообще без height будет работать криво - от высоты контента зависит высота body, а следовательно и заполнение градиентом.